# Use javascript to add select field with values from database

Tags: javascript, php, database

I want to add a select field to a formular. Actually it would be no problem to do it with javascript. However, the options of the select field come from a database. The only way I figured out was to create a function in php called `returnSelect()` that returns the desired select field and to call it in my javascript code like this:

```
...
wrapper.append('<td><?php echo $Kernel->gI("Balanceapp")->returnSelect(...); ?></td>');
...
```

It works just fine. However, that feels like a very clunky way to do it. I don't think it is good practice either, so is there another, more proper way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you load the drop down while parsing the page itself? Is your page is .php? Is there any particular reason you need to do it via JS?

Comment: Because I dont want it to be shown initially. The user shall be able to add the select field via a button that calls a js function

Comment: You could return the results from that function with an AJAX call when the button is clicked and append the HTML. I probably wouldn't append it how you are currently doing, I would just add it too the HTML originally (via PHP) and hide the element with CSS and then show the element on the button click.

Comment: oh.. that is such a simple yet smart way. Thanks, I will do it like this.